# In Google Analytics what is the relationship between "Event" and "Site Usage" in behavior / events / pages / report

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

In behavior / events / pages there are 2 options. "Event" and "Site Usage". What is the relationship between these two settings.

When i select a page such as "/payment" and action "MyAction" i get the below results.

1. "Event" view: Total events = 3,625
2. "Site Usage" view: Sessions = 4

In the business logic of our application these 2 values should be closer together. Noticably, the "Site Usage" only having 4 sessions looks suspicious.

To give a broader outline what i'm trying to achieve. I'd like to know the page duration of a user on "/payment" and has the action "MyAction" over the past month.

Comment: I do not have an explanation, but I can say this discrepancy is not just you - in our GA, the Events Overview report says that nearly 80% of our sessions include events, but the session total in the Site Usage metric group under Events > Pages is less than 2% of our sessions. The Pages/Session metric is 0.00 for every entry, as well. This is in a production site with internal traffic filtered out, and without restricting events by category/action/label.

Answer (score 1):

In GA, the event is just a browser specific event captured and pushed to Google Analytics storage. This could be any event that happens (and that can be captured by javascript).

A session is defined as a group of interactions one user takes within a given time frame (30 mins) on your website. So the report you are saying is that 4 distinct sessions managed to fire this event 3625 times.

Whereas I agree that the numbers should have been much closer, this kind of disparity usually means one thing. That a developer has been working (and testing) the flow and very few users actually have hit that page. Try to see the impact of these numbers with Users during that same period. Users and Sessions would be much closer. Another thing you might check is the way the event has been implemented, perhaps it's being fired when it should not be fired (e.g a conversion event on a page-view).